# Incompatible key type SET<Id> for MAP<Id,String>: save Error

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

i have a map

```
  Map<id,String>    map1= new Map<id,String>();
```

I am assigning values into this map

```
  map1.put(aList[j].id,err.getMessage()); // err is the database.error and aList is a list of accounts.
```

i am trying to loop through all the map records and i get a error here
       Save error: Incompatible key type SET for MAP

```
  for(set<id> ids : map1.KeySet())
    {
        system.debug(map1.get(ids));// i get a error here  
    }
```

Any ideas what could be causing this
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i must have gone blind

```
for(set<id> ids : map1.KeySet())
```

should be

```
for(id ids : map1.KeySet())
```

Comment: why are these -ve markings? just because i found the solution myself? If someone else had pointed it out, there might not be -ve markings :)